# Joined records as array of json in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I'd like to return records in a table I'm joining to as an array of jsons inside a single field.

I have a working-ish solution but there is an undesired `f1` insdie it.

**Current query:**

```
select 
    grouped_by_table.json_array as my_col
from profiles
left join (
    select 
        p.profile_id,
        array_to_json(array_agg(row(p))) as json_array
    from (select * from positions) p
    group by profile_id
) as grouped_by_table on grouped_by_table.profile_id::int = profiles.id
```

**Current result:**
*(This is the data in `my_col` column for a single record)*

```
[{
    "f1": {
        "id": 153,
        "start_year": 2014,
        "end_year": 2016,
        "profile_id": "100"
    }
}, {
    "f1": {
        "id": 151,
        "start_year": 2016,
        "end_year": null,
        "profile_id": "100"
    }
}]
```

**Desired result:**
*(I'd like to remove the `f1` layer)*

```
[{
    "id": 153,
    "start_year": 2014,
    "end_year": 2016,
    "profile_id": "100"
}, {
    "id": 151,
    "start_year": 2016,
    "end_year": null,
    "profile_id": "100"
}]
```

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`json_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) instead of `array_agg`:

```
select  profile_id
,       json_agg(p)
from    positions p
group by
        profile_id
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6b9d6/13/0)